# Can the 12-inch macbook charge from USB-A?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging

While it's nice to have a laptop that can charge over a standard cable, USB-C is not yet ubiquitous. USB-A is: you can be sure that whatever hotel room or office you visit, you will find a place to plug in your USB-A charging cable.

If I buy a USB-A to USB-C cable, will it allow me to charge my 12 inch macbook (however slowly)? Is it safe to try?

Comment: @Allan, I don't see this question as a duplicate that you linked. That question doesn't mention anything specific about the type of USB connector and whether or not a USB-A to USB-C connector/cable can be used.

Comment: @Allan I think that question is about MacBooks in general, not the USB-C variety. [This article](http://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-survive-with-only-one-usb-c-port-on-your-new-macbook/) seems to suggest that the 12 inch _can_ be charged from a battery pack. (Which would suggest the answer to this question is yes also).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Can a Macbook charge it's batteries from a USB-A charger (car or wall) or battery pack?

It depends, but yes, it *should* work.  The charging performance may vary from it charges very slowly to not at all.

"Type A" is the [connector type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Connector_types); it has nothing to do with how much power is being delivered.  What you need is a power adapter that is compliant to USB 3.1 specifications.  It just so happens that to connect it to your MacBook, you need a "Type C" connector.

Would I recommend you doing this?  ***Absolutely not.***

**Important Note:**  Plugging into a power source that is significantly lower than what is required by your device can and will [damage your equipment](https://superuser.com/questions/247312/laptop-power-supplies-does-current-matter).

---

### Why?

First, we need to know what the power requirements are to power the [Macbook](http://www.apple.com/macbook/specs/); per Apple, it requires a 29W USB-C Power Adapter (see below).

[image]

Generally speaking, the USB Type A adapters most people are familiar with are those that charge their iDevices.  These are based on USB 2.0 at best and according to the [specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_3.1), they are limited to 5V 1.5A.

[image]

That means, those chargers are limited to 7.5W.

```
(Watts = Volts * Amps)
```

7.5W  is nowhere enough to power your Macbook.

[image]

If you notice in the above USB 3.0 pin out diagram, there is only 1 5V (VCC) pin (this is important in understanding USB 3.1 further down).

The USB 3.1 is the specification that says it will support up to 20V at 5A.  Using the same equation from above we get a specification that is capable of handling up to 100W so there's enough power "bandwidth" to charge your Macbook.  But that's using a special communications protocol over a USB-C cable.

```
20V * 5A = 100W
```

However, the basic spec is still the same, 5V but now at 3A and there are **two** 5 volt pins as opposed to only one for USB 3.0 and earlier.  This means combined you can get 10V.

[image]

If you notice in this pin out diagram there are two 5V pins (Vbus).  These are combined to make 10V.

**Note:**   *There are some USB 3.1 Type A adapters out in the wild, but they are so few and far between I wasn't able to find a schematic for the pinouts.  I am using Type C since these are the most common.*

So using our trusty equation again,

```
(2x 5V) * 3A = 10V * 3A = 30W
```

30W is within spec of charging your Macbook.

**But what about the cable?**  Plugging in a USB 3.1 (A to C) into a non-USB 3.1 power adapter will **not** fix the problem.  The adapter is only providing 5 volts on one pin, not on two that's required to get the appropriate amount of current.

Comment: Wouldn't a 3.1 Type-A to 3.1 Type-C cable work, assuming the Type-A port was 3.1 spec? Though few and far between, there are [a few products out there](http://www.asus.com/microsite/mb/best_usb31_solutions/) that support USB 3.1 with a Type-A connector.


The point I'm trying to make is that your answer, though very good, is a little misleading in that it seems to point towards USB Type-A being the culprit rather than <USB 3.1 as the culprit.

Comment: @JMY1000 I tried to emphasize it was 3.1 and not the Type A that was important.  Where is it misleading so I can fix?

Comment: "No. Period." This seems to point towards USB Type-A being the problem. [Also, it looks like other power delivery profiles are available for the 3.0 spec](http://www.usb.org/developers/powerdelivery/PD_1.0_Introduction.pdf)  that up the voltage, meaning that 3.0 might be compatible.

Comment: In addition, the way that the pin-out diagrams were addressed makes the Type-A connector seem like the culprit. Using a Type-A 3.1/3.0 connector would probably make sense, then showing how that translates into a Type-C connector that can supply enough power.

Comment: I must admit I'm not entirely convinced. Firstly, there's a difference between powering and charging. Sure, maybe the battery will drain if I use it while keeping it plugged in, but if I leave it overnight, will it still charge? Second, Google [states](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6164519?hl=en) that the chromebook pixel _can_  be charged from "most USB-A ports", which suggests USB 2.0 as well. Finally, the article linked in the comments above shows people charging the macbook from an old powerbank with a USB-A port.

Comment: Not to dismiss you post, of course, but I'm having trouble fitting all the evidence together.

Comment: @JMY1000 The spec for USB 3.0 (and earlier) is that the connector can *handle* up to 5A of current not that it's going to provide it.  The photo I used was a 3.0 Type A connector.  I can't find a Type A 3.1 connector picture but if one existed it would provide the necessary power.

Comment: @Peter  I don't know what to say.  I am not being dismissive either but it fascinates me when people are bewildered when their products' lifespan is cut arbitrarily short after attempting "hacks" based on seeing "articles."   Did you notice they didn't specifically say you could do it?

Comment: @Allan, well they link to a place to buy the cable. That's not something a big company like Google would do. I'm not saying I'm I'm going to plug my laptop into expensive hardware on the basis of an article, I just want to figure out what would actually happen. Your answer says "No. period." when the actual answer seems to be "You'll get a slow charge, but there are risks for the hardware on the USB-A side, depending on the specification it follows".

Comment: Do you remember the article about the Google engineer who was testing USB 3.1 cables?  He fried his Chromebook.  My advice is based on the risk analysis of a $5 cable and a $2000 laptop.  I would **never** tell anyone to use other that what is specified (or even try).

Comment: @Allan I'm not questioning your advice, I agree with it. But advice is not an answer. The answer to "could I tattoo myself at home with a needle and a byro?" should be accompanied by a warning, but the answer is still yes. I'm just trying to figure out how it works, exactly. For instance, can a good 3.1 cable still fry a (poor) 2.0 port? Remember that it's a data port as well, so someone could just be attempting to use the cable for data-transfer.

Comment: I can fix my answer to reflect that.  As for the cable, there are two components:  the cable and the adapter.  If the adapter is poorly designed it could allow the wrong signal on a data pin thereby frying your equipment.

Comment: The statement that two 5 V pins combined make for 10 V in total is false. In fact, the USB-C connector even has four power supply pins, but they are all connected to the same wire internally. The higher voltages specified by USB-C are sent over the same wires and pins after a handshake between the two devices.

Comment: I lol'd at "the two 5V pins are combined to make 10 V". Electricity doesn't work that way, unless one was -5 V (which it isn't).

Answer (score 3):

My MacBook Pro charges with a Belkin Mixit USB- C to USB-A cable and an Apple 10W USB power adapter that came with my old iPad.

I also tested the same cable with the iPhone usb charger but it didn't charge. It was however, able to keep the power level even indicating a power stalemate which is a half a win.

Comment: I can confirm this works. It charges, albeit extremely slow and not under heavy use, but it charges.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you *might* be able to do this..  My only evidence for that statement is from [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00URK1V1U) USB-A to USB-C cable on Amazon and the associated product reviews.

Dozens of users state that they use it, albeit very slowly, to charge their MacBooks. However, one user, who has the very first review and is rated as 'most helpful' provides technical details as to why you shouldn't use it this way because it could damage the MacBook.  Even Apple, [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204360) states:

> USB hubs and other USB devices that supply power won't charge your MacBook. Use the supplied 29W USB-C Power Adapter and USB-C Charge Cable to charge your MacBook.

Comment: It seems like the problem with that cable is that it doesn't follow the USB 3.1 spec properly. The google engineer that wrote that review does give [other cables](https://www.amazon.com/iOrange-Braided-Stepped-Connector-ChromeBook/dp/B01B7R419K/ref=cm_rdp_product) five stars, and seems to suggest that they're safe.

Comment: @Peter.  A 3.1 cable will not make a 3.0 and previous adapter capable of powering a USB 3.1 device.