# Can I use the USB-C Apple adapter, to charge my MacBook 12', with USB-A port?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging

I have:

- MacBook 12"
- [USB-C AV Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter)
- [USB-A to USB-C cable](https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4974/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/H/HS/HHSP2/HHSP2_AV1?wid=1000&hei=1000&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1463597567547)
- [USB-C Macbook 12' charger](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*uPfC1ukMWAOl-ABmSfeL4g.jpeg)

Basically I want to keep the USB-C port on the adapter free.

So, instead of using a USB-C cable to plug the charger to the adapter, I want to use the USB-A port on the adapter.

Will this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the 12-inch macbook charge from USB-A?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242875/can-the-12-inch-macbook-charge-from-usb-a)

Comment: @anothernode The other question doesn't include USB-C AV Multiport Adapter

Comment: Okay, I see, it's surely not an obvious duplicate. To my understanding the accepted answer there still does answer your question.You are using a USB-A to USB-C cable in the chain, which will only allow for 5V current because it must follow the USB-A specification. So the answer applies: it might charge the MacBook very slowly but it's not advisable to try.

Comment: @anothernode - There's no USB-A power delivery specification.  There's USB 3.0 and 3.1  The type A port conforms to the 3.0 spec while the USB-C  conforms to the 3.1.  You can have a 3.1 type A port - they are very few and far between, but they can and do exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, this will not work.  You cannot charge through the USB-A port.**

The USB-A port is a 3.0 port which will **supply** 5V of power, but it will not be able to negotiate to **receive** power per the USB 3.1 spec.

Per the [Multiport AV Adapter specifications](https://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter):

> Use the standard USB port to connect devices such as your flash drive
>   or camera, or a USB cable for syncing and charging your iPhone, iPad
>   or iPod. **You can also connect a charging cable to the USB-C port to
>   charge your Mac**.